# not able to move images to another folder in gallery, using asynctask

Tags: java, android, image, file, android-asynctask

I created an image gallery app.

**My requirment**: I want to select multiple images, click on button cut and come back to activity which displays all folders (ImageGallery.java). Now, I want to select a folder and paste all the selected images in that folder, on selecting the folder.

**What is happening**? I am able to select images using my app and come back to activity which displays all folders but not able to move them using my app.
I put the code for moving images in a background thread using task. I select images from one folder, come back to the activity which displays all the folders *(ImageGallery.java)* and select the folder to which the images are to be moved.  But when I try to move images, selected images do not move to other folder being selected, on selecting a folder. I guess the code inside AsyncTask isn't even getting executed.

How do I fix it ?

**PhotosActivity.java** (Activity used to select images):

```
int int_position;
private GridView gridView;
GridViewAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Integer> mSelected = new ArrayList<>();
boolean boolean_folder;

gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            if (mSelected.contains(position)) {
                mSelected.remove(position);
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);// remove item from list
                // update view (v) state here
                // eg: remove highlight
            } else {
                mSelected.add(position);
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);// add item to list
                // update view (v) state here
                // eg: add highlight
            }

            buttoncut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            buttoncut.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            buttoncut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            button3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            button4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            button5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Intent moveIntent = new Intent(PhotosActivity.this, ImageGallery.class);
                            moveIntent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("selected_images", mSelected);
                            startActivity(moveIntent);
                        }
                    });
```

**ImageGallery.java**:

```
public static ArrayList<Model_images> al_images = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> selectedImages = new ArrayList<>();
boolean boolean_folder;
Adapter_PhotosFolder obj_adapter;
GridView gv_folder;
private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 100;
int int_position;

selectedImages = getIntent().getIntegerArrayListExtra("selected_images");

if (selectedImages != null) {
    Toast.makeText(ImageGallery.this, "This code gets executed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
    new LongOperation().execute();
}

private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {   
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        for (int image : selectedImages) {

            File sourceImage = new File(al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(image)); //returns the image File from model class to be moved.
            File destinationImage = new File(al_images.get(int_position).getStr_folder(), ".jpeg");

            try {
                copyOrMoveFile(sourceImage, destinationImage, true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    //Method to move the file
    private void copyOrMoveFile(File file, File dir, boolean isCopy) throws IOException {
        File newFile = new File(dir, file.getName());
        FileChannel outChannel = null;
        FileChannel inputChannel = null;
        try {
            outChannel = new FileOutputStream(newFile).getChannel();
            inputChannel = new FileInputStream(file).getChannel();
            inputChannel.transferTo(0, inputChannel.size(), outChannel);
            inputChannel.close();
            if (!isCopy)
                file.delete();
        } finally {
            if (inputChannel != null) inputChannel.close();
            if (outChannel != null) outChannel.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `File sourceImage = new File(al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(image)); //returns the image File from model class to be moved.
                File destinationImage = new File(al_images.get(int_position).getStr_folder(), ".jpeg");`. You try to copy files. Please give some values of `sourceImage.getAbsolutePath()` and `destinationImage.getAbsolutePath()`.

Comment: which android version are you using? do you have write permissions in manifest or requested? example value of full input and full output path?

Comment: It is strange that you use file paths as that is something you dont get from the media store. You did not explain how your code should work or what you are doing. Its time you do.

Comment: You let doInBackground always return null. Now how would you know if all is copied? Let it return different strings and if there is a catch then return e.getMessage().

Comment: You should not look in 'the gallery' or your own gridview to see if you copied/moved a file. Just use a file explorer app on your device to see if the file appears in the destination folder.

Comment: `void copyOrMoveFile()`. Bad idea to make it void. Make it a boolean function so the caller knows if the copy is done.

Comment: Use onPostExecute() to display the string returned by doInBackground().

Comment: What should I be using , if not file paths ? @greenapps

Comment: Well what did you get from the media store to begin with? Repeat: `Please give some values of sourceImage.getAbsolutePath() and destinationImage.getAbsolutePath(). `.

Comment: add catch in your copyOrMoveFile and print it with Log.e(~), and post error msg from android logcat

Comment: android nougat , yes, I have all the permissions @k3b

Comment: not getting any error msg , seems like Asynctask code isn't even getting executed @bskim45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` for updating media store.

Inside AsyncTask -> onPostExecute method fetch latest images from **MediaStore**

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, File> {

        @Override
        protected File doInBackground(String... params) {

            for (String imagePath : selectedImages) {
                File sourceImage = new File(imagePath); //returns the image File from model class to
                // be// moved.
                File destinationImage = new File(al_images.get(int_position).getDirectoryPath() +
                        File.separator + sourceImage.getName());

                try {
                    moveFile(sourceImage, destinationImage, true);
                    return destinationImage;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(File file) {
            super.onPostExecute(file);
            getBaseContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(file)));
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    fn_imagespath(); // Call method to fetch latest images.
                }
            }, 1000); // additional delay time of 1 sec to update media scanner
        }
    }
```

Just a better method to move file

```
private void moveFile(File file_Source, File file_Destination, boolean isCopy) throws IOException {
        FileChannel source = null;
        FileChannel destination = null;
        if (!file_Destination.exists()) {
            file_Destination.createNewFile();
        }

        try {
            source = new FileInputStream(file_Source).getChannel();
            destination = new FileOutputStream(file_Destination).getChannel();

            long count = 0;
            long size = source.size();
            while ((count += destination.transferFrom(source, count, size - count)) < size) ;
            if (!isCopy) {
                file_Source.delete();
            }
        } finally {
            if (source != null) {
                source.close();
            }
            if (destination != null) {
                destination.close();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: The `return destinationImage;` code will only move one image as it will break the for loop and resulting in the loop being executed only once.

Answer (score 1):

Not much changes in code added `MediaScannerConnection`. Give it a try .

```
 private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        int movedCount=0;
        for (int i=0;i<selectedImages.size();i++) {
            File sourceImage = new File(al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(i));
            File destinationImage = new File(al_images.get(int_position).getStr_folder(), ".jpeg");
            try {
              boolean isMoved= copyOrMoveFile(sourceImage, destinationImage, true);
                if(isMoved) {
                    movedCount++;
                    callMediaScanner(ImageGallery.this, destinationImage.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return movedCount;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer val) {
        super.onPostExecute(val);
        // Here you have to modify return type of doInBackground as per your convineance
        if(val.intValue()==selectedImages.size()){
            Log.e("Moved","Allfile moved");
        }else{
            Log.e("Moved","Some file missing");
        }
    }
    public boolean copyOrMoveFile(File localFile, File destinationFile, boolean isCopy) {
            FileChannel outputChannel = null;
            FileChannel inputChannel = null;
            try {
                outputChannel = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile).getChannel();
                inputChannel = new FileInputStream(localFile).getChannel();
                inputChannel.transferTo(0, inputChannel.size(), outputChannel);
                inputChannel.close();
                if (!isCopy)
                    localFile.delete();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (inputChannel != null) inputChannel.close();
                    if (outputChannel != null) outputChannel.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

public void callMediaScanner(Context context, String path) {
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
            new String[] { path }, null,null);
}
```

Comment: Its working at my end . If you still faced problem then try to Debug each Step in AsyncTask and see whats happening.